# Two different values for same memory address?

Tags: c

I was trying to understand how `const` works with pointers, and I tried modifying the value pointed by a pointer of a pointer to `const`. I expected it to fail, but I can't understand what happens.

```c
const int n = 1;
int *p = &n;
*p = 2;
printf("%d %d\n", *p, n);
printf("%p %p\n", p, &n);
printf("%d %d", *p==n, p==&n);
```

The result I'm getting shows that `*p` has a different value from `n`, but still `p` is the same location as `&n`. What is happening here?

Comment: Welcome to the world of undefined behavior.

Comment: `int *p = &n;` how does this even compile?

Comment: @KamilCuk: this is worse than random. Where could the second value be stored?

Comment: As far as the C standard is concerned, this code is literally meaningless. (Also, `int *p = &n` is a type error.)

Comment: Compiler optimisations: The first `printf` is optimized to become `printf("%d %d\n", *p, 1);` because you have told the compiler that `n` is constant. Even though your program might compile with warnings, all uses of `n` can have the value 1.

Comment: Similarly, the third printf will become `printf("%d %d", *p==1, p==&n);`. In fact, the compiler may optimize even further, replacing `p==&n` with 1(true).

Comment: @blue_note Yes, Undefined Behavior can be worse than random, seeming to work sometimes, and then breaking for seemingly unrelated reasons. As for how this result actually happens, it's probably the compiler's optimizations: it "knows" the value of `n` will always be `1`, so it just uses that value directly rather than reading from any memory location.

Comment: ... and in particular, @blue_note, *"undefined" does not mean random*, at least not in the probabilistic sense.  Undefined behavior can manifest in ways that seem quite deterministic.  The term should be interpreted quite literally: the language does not define the behavior that ensues.  As far as the language is concerned, any effect or effects within the machine's capability to produce can occur, can *have* occurred before, and can *continue* to occur afterward.

Comment: I'm having trouble to understand what bothers you about ```int *p = &n```? This sounds legit to me, isn't it?